# Исключения, когда их включать в код?

Tags: исключения

Как обычно все проблемы мои с java из-за ее неопределенности. Вроде есть исключение, я знаю библиотеку исключений, знаю синтаксис кода. Но когда мне их прописывать? Библиотека исключений огромная, получается мне нужно при каждом написании каждой строчки думать : а будет ли здесь исключение?? И какое?? И так мне надо делать постоянно?

Comment: В зависимости то того, что вы хотите сделать - нужно продумать где возможно будет ошибка. Будет ли это ввод данных - пользователь ввёл некорректные данные (ожидался int, а ввели string напр.). В этом месте располагаете блоки try/catch и гуглите название соотв. исключения (или пишите своё исключение) - данном случае это InvalidDataException для C#. Всё просто до ужаса. Попробуйте написать подобный пример и всё станет ясно.

Comment: Неопределенность у вас, а не у Java (= Осознайте преимущества исключений, то что стандартные исключения там не абы как расположены, а иерархически, поймите, когда клиенту (клиентскому коду) важно знать о проблеме, а когда - нет. Когда нужно исключение, а когда достаточно возвратить пустую коллекцию/null/nullable-state объект/код возврата/текст ошибки. Читайте чужой код в конце концов!

Comment: @free_ze верные слова пишите. Может оформите как ответ, чтобы все видели, и вопрос не оказался закрыт?